# Is batching queries to FQL with per-request access_tokens not allowed? It isn't working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery, facebook-batch-request

Is it not possible to batch query the graph using 'method/fql.query?query=...' using multiple access tokens?

I have never had trouble in the past batch querying non-fql endpoints with multiple access tokens, but with batch querying FQL calls, only the first call returns data, the rest return an empty body.

The only guess I can make is that it is access_token related, but if so I'm sort of at a loss for how to remedy..

Example:

```
import json
from pyfaceb import *

user1_tk = '...' #valid token (tested)
user1_qry = '...' #valid query (tested unbatched)
user1_rqst = {'method': 'POST', 'relative_url': 'method/fql.query?query=' + user1_qry, 'access_token': user1_tk}

user2_tk = '...' #valid token (tested)
user2_qry = '...' #valid query (tested unbatched)
user2_rqst = {'method': 'POST', 'relative_url': 'method/fql.query?query=' + user2_qry, 'access_token': user2_tk}

batches = [user1_rqst, user2_rqst]

fbg = FBGraph(user1_tk) # use user1_tk as fallback access token (cuz you have to specify one)
data = fbg.get_batch(batches)

print data[0]['body'] #comes back with data, but
print data[1]['body'] #comes back as an empty array.
```

Both data[0]['code'] and data[1]['code'] are HTTP 200 responses.

If I change the fallback access token to user2_tk, then data[0]['body'] comes back as an empty array (i.e. vice versa). Even though I'm specifying access_tokens for each request (per: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/#differentaccesstokens)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The acccess_token needs to be in the request body, as it is a POST:

```
...
user1_rqst = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'relative_url': 'method/fql.query?query=' + user1_qry,
    'body': 'access_token=' + user1_tk
}

...

user2_rqst = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'relative_url': 'method/fql.query?query=' + user2_qry,
    'body': 'access_token=' + user2_tk
}
```